# How to use an NT auth connection in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, active-directory

I am attempting to connect to a Microsoft SQL server db using PHP (in IIS). The user/pass provided in the code is an AD account that can access the database via ODBC in Access just fine.

```
$serverName = "servername";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"myuser", "PWD"=>"mypass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br /><pre>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

The username and password are valid, as are the server name and database name. But this is returning the error:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myuser'.

For the username (which is a valid user in AD, and I can connect/link to this database using Access) I've also tried:

- DOMAIN.ORG\myuser
- DOMAIN.ORG\\myuser
- myuser@DOMAIN.ORG

My domain user (`myuser`) has admin privileges to that server via AD. But that returns the same `Login failed` error. Is there something I'm missing? I can connect to this same db using Access without a problem (under the same user).

The way I connect in Access is an ODBC Data Source for the local user. The Data Source is set to authenticate "With Windows NT authentication using the network login ID". How can I do that in PHP?

Is [this impersonation configuration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/02/10/sql-server-driver-for-php-understanding-windows-authentication.aspx) the possible cause?

PHP is running under the user `nt authority\iusr`

If it was trying to login using `iusr` wouldn't the error message say so?

I've tried creating a Data Source on this machine called "TestDS" and using the code:

```
$conn = odbc_connect("TestDS", "", "");
```

But that gives me:

> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application, SQL state IM014 in SQLConnect

Machine1 is a client trying to access a webpage (where the PHP code is on Machine2) and the code on Machine2 is making the SQL connection to Machine3 (`servername`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Windows Security" in SQL Server connections is enabled by specifying "Trusted Connection=SSPI" in the connection string. No username or password is stored in the connection string (that's only for "SQL Server Security"). The process running PHP (presumably php_cgi.exe itself) must run under a Windows (either local or AD) that has a Windows login registered on the SQL Server.

Under IIS php_cgi.exe runs under the user identity of the application pool. If you have a heterogenous security environment I suggest creating an IIS application pool just for this single website.

Comment: I made an edit to my question. So I should be adding a local user `iusr` to the SQL server?

Comment: Yes, but then use the "Trusted Connection" option in your connection string instead of Username/Password. Note that if your SQL Server is located on a different physical machine (and you don't have an Active Directory trust relationship between the machines) then you will have to use SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows auth.

Comment: I went with SQL authentication.